# NodeFinder equivalent in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

There is a [NodeFinder](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FNodeFinder.html) in org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom that can find the ASTNode in a given source code range. However, I am using a library that has [ecj.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj) as its Java compiler. The package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast in ECJ looks very similar to org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom, but I don't know how to get the ASTNode in a source range. I can't find documentation/source code for ecj.jar. Google search for either "ecj" or "Eclipse Compiler for Java" directed me to the EClipse JDT Core page, which doesn't have doc for org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast. Any help?

Also, I am curious about why Eclipse has two Java compilers, that confuse me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that writing a `NodeFinder` for ecj was not hard. I wrote one and customized it for my special case.